# Getting java to display the correct amount of decrements

Tags: java, android, variable-assignment

I am making an app which is a guessing game between 1 and 100. The current version I am writing gives the player 7 tries to to find the correct guess. I have created a variable to display how many guesses the player has left, however once the player has guessed, the number of guesses decrements by more than one (usually two).

So basically the numberOfGuesses var. will decrement every time the checkGuess() method is run. I have tried placing the decrement in the event listener for when the player presses the button, but it's still decrementing by more than one. There is a setOnClick listener if the player clicks the mouse button too, and another for the enter button. When I use the button in the game, it decrements properly. When I use the ENTER button, it decrements by two. Is it running the button listener when I press ENTER?

I tried changing decrement from numberOfGuesses--; to --numberOfGuesses;

I tried assigning it as numberOfGuesses = numberOfGuesses - 1;

Here is the variables wiring to thew GUI, and the checkGuess() method

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText txtGuess;
    private Button btnGuess;
    private TextView lblOutput;
    private int theNumber;
    private int numberOfTries = 7;

    public void checkGuess() {
        String guessText = txtGuess.getText().toString();//
        String message = "";
        try {
            --numberOfTries;
            int guess = Integer.parseInt(guessText);
            if (guess > theNumber)
                message = guess + " is too high. You have " +numberOfTries + " " + " tries left! ";



            else if (guess < theNumber)
                message = guess + " is too low. You have " +numberOfTries + " " + " tries left! ";


            else{
                message = guess +
                        " is correct! You finished with " +numberOfTries + " tries left. Let's play again!";
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message,
                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                newGame();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            message = "Enter a whole number between 1 and 100.";
        } finally {
            lblOutput.setText(message);
            txtGuess.requestFocus();
            txtGuess.selectAll();
```

The newGame() method which generates a new random number

```
 public void newGame(){

        theNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
        numberOfTries = 7;

    }
```

Here is the method which runs on execution of app

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtGuess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtGuess);
        btnGuess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGuess);
        lblOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblOutput);
        newGame();
        btnGuess.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkGuess();
            }
        });
        txtGuess.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
               checkGuess();
               return true;
            }
        });
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

I am expecting the numberOfGuesses to decrement from 7 to 6, but the actual output is decrementing from 7 to 5, when I use enter, it works as I want for the button click (or at least displaying as 7 to 5),

Answer (score 0):

Pressing enter while the text field is selected would trigger the OnEditorActionListener (and so would any other change, as far as I can tell).  Have you tried filtering that Listener by actionId to make sure it only goes off specifically for the enter key?

Comment: Do I have to create a new action Id for the enter button, or is there one pre-assigned? I'm not sure how to reference to the enter key, could you please advise if possible